# Pre-dual of the measure space $\mathcal{M}(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, dual-spaces, borel-measures

I have to find the 'pre-dual of the measure space $\mathcal{M}(X)$'. $X$ can be assumed to be Polish and equipped with the Borel $\sigma$ algebra. This is all I'm given and it's a bit vague. What I found so far is this:
if $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff, then any element in the dual of $C_c(X)$ (the space of continuous compactly supported complex-valued functions on $X$) corresponds to a unique regular Borel measure on $X$, i.e. for $\psi \in (C_c(X))'$, we have
$$\psi(f)=\int_X f(x) \,d\mu(x)$$ for such a measure $\mu$. But do we 'hit' all such measures, i.e. can we really identify the dual of $C_c(X)$ with the space of regular Borel measures? Would the mapping $\psi\mapsto\mu$ only be bijective, or can we make it, say, into an isomorphism (using the total variation norm)? Is there another space whose dual is the space of *all* Borel measures on $X$, without making the assumptions that $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff? (Also, if you know good literature on this please let me know, I was having a hard time finding something.)
(Edit: for anyone interested (and German speaking): Funktionalanalysis by Dirk Werner seems to cover the topic well.)

Comment: For your locally compact case, yes, it is bijective.  The surjectivity is trivial, since $f \mapsto \int f\,d\mu$ is a continuous linear functional on $C_c(X)$.  And yes, the total variation norm makes it an isometry.  These are all usually considered part of the [Riesz-Markov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem); you've only stated the hardest part of it.

Comment: The non-locally compact case is harder and I don't know if there is a good answer.  It might be something like the bounded continuous functions with a weaker topology.